# Show that language is not a regular language by using the pumping lemma or closure

Tags: computer-science, regular-language, finite-automata

c. $\{w| w ∈ {0,1}^∗$ $ \text{is not a palindrome}\}^8$

The 8 confuses me a little bit. Can someone clear up what the 8 means?. Is it a typo in the problem?

Comment: The 8 is definitely a typo

Comment: @Samasambo ok, so I believe I have to use the complement of the language and prove it's not regular right?

Comment: Correct, regular languages are closed under complementation.